# CSS bullets align but now float

Tags: css, html-lists

How do I align CSS bullets to the outer text but keep the text displaying as a block?

This is what I've tried but none of them do what I want.

```css
.list_container {
  max-width:300px;
  text-align:left;
  margin:10px 10px;
  font-size:12px;
}

.list_container ul {
 lit-style-type:disc;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

.list_span {
  display:inline-block;
}

.list_span2 {
  padding-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list_container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    <ul style="list-style-position:outside;">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="list_container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    <ul style="list-style-position:inside;">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="list_container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    <ul style="list-style-position:inside;">
        <li><span class="list_span">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></li>
        <li><span class="list_span">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></li>
        <li><span class="list_span">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="list_container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    <ul style="list-style-position:inside;">
        <li><span class="list_span2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></li>
        <li><span class="list_span2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></li>
        <li><span class="list_span2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is this:

[image]

Comment: Why not just set a left margin on the `<ul>`?

Comment: @j08691 I could do that but I don't know how to determine what I should set the margin to so that it remains correct regardless of font-size and screen size.

Comment: I'd use `1em` but if you feel that doesn't work for you, try another unit

Comment: @j08691 That does seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding-left` on the `ul` - I used 0.8em as a value:

```css
.list_container {
  max-width:300px;
  text-align:left;
  margin:10px 10px;
  font-size:12px;
}

.list_container ul {
 list-style-type:disc;
 padding-left:0.8em;
 
}

.list_span {
  display:inline-block;
}

.list_span2 {
  padding-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list_container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    <ul style="list-style-position:outside;">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="list_container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    <ul style="list-style-position:inside;">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="list_container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    <ul style="list-style-position:inside;">
        <li><span class="list_span">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></li>
        <li><span class="list_span">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></li>
        <li><span class="list_span">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="list_container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    <ul style="list-style-position:inside;">
        <li><span class="list_span2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></li>
        <li><span class="list_span2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></li>
        <li><span class="list_span2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to give those `li`'s a class (I called it `.left`) and use the `::before` psuedo to adjust the spacing. It should look something like this:

```css
li.left::before {
  content: "";
  margin-left: -.6em;
}
```

See it here:

```css
.list_container {
  max-width: 300px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.list_container ul {
  lit-style-type: disc;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.list_span2 {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.list_span {
  display: inline-block;
}

li.left::before {
  content: "";
  margin-left: -.6em;
}
```

```html
<div class="list_container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    <ul style="list-style-position:outside;">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="list_container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    <ul style="list-style-position:inside;">
        <li class="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
        <li class="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
        <li class="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="list_container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    <ul style="list-style-position:inside;">
        <li><span class="list_span">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></li>
        <li><span class="list_span">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></li>
        <li><span class="list_span">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="list_container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    <ul style="list-style-position:inside;">
        <li><span class="list_span2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></li>
        <li><span class="list_span2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></li>
        <li><span class="list_span2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be absolutely sure that you get alignment whatever the font size and other spacing we need to position the disc ourselves.

This snippet does this by removing the default browser style and instead putting the disc on via its Unicode character in a before pseudo element.

The li elements are given a margin (in this demo 1em but it could be anything you want) and the pseudo element is given that margin negative.

```css
.list_container {
  max-width: 300px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.list_container ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.list_container ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.list_container ul li::before {
  content: '\2022';
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="list_container">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  <ul style="list-style-position:outside;">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```